# How to convert text files to pdf files in python script?

Tags: python, pdf, text

I have a report text file, which is created by my python script. I want to create pdf file from mentioned text file in python script. After searching, I came across reportlab library, but in tutorials of same library it shows creating pdf having manually written contents.However I want to convert my text file to pdf file.

Is there any other option, any script?

thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried to write some code to open the file, read the text, pass it to reportlab (nb: i used http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/ as an alternative...) and then generate your pdf? "no i didn't, i'll try then post again eventually" ;)

Comment: I'm not sure of any "automatic" options besides using an HTML -> PDF converter. There are a few open source options out there but the conversion isn't always clean. If your text file is relatively normalized and you know what to expect, you could open it in python, read the file contents, and parse them into variables which you could pass into reportlab objects (Tables, Paragraphs, etc). It would be useful to see some example data and what you expect the PDF output to look like.

Comment: @Samuele Mattiuzzi: Not yet, I want to have suggestion from all you folks to start with. I will be waiting then for you post. :)                  As I manage to write some code, will share it.

Comment: @Nitzle: Yes, I have thought of that. Actually I am querying database and storing the output information in a text file with some formatting. Then I thought of making a pdf from that text file. The solution you suggested would be easy to implement, as for writing to text file I am first taking those data in local variables, then at same time I can put them in pdf as well. I will go through some examples to create pdf from scratch. Thank you.